# Correlation heatmap turned values into nan in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, nan

I want to conduct a heatmap on my table `df`, which looks normal at the beginning:

```
    Total   Paid Post Engaged   Negative    like 
1   2178    0    0    66        0           1207
2   1042    0    0    60        0           921
3   2096    0    0    112       0           1744
4   1832    0    0    109       0           1718
5   1341    0    0    38        0           889
6   1933    0    0    123       0           1501
    ...
```

but after I applied:

```
df= full_Data.iloc[1:,4:10]
df= pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

corrMatrix = df.corr()
sn.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

it returned an empty graph:

```
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py:204: RuntimeWarning: All-NaN slice encountered
  vmin = np.nanmin(calc_data)
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py:209: RuntimeWarning: All-NaN slice encountered
  vmax = np.nanmax(calc_data)
```

[image]

and `df` returned:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   nan nan nan nan nan nan
2   nan nan nan nan nan nan
3   nan nan nan nan nan nan
4   nan nan nan nan nan nan
5   nan nan nan nan nan nan
    ...
```

Why all the values are turned into `nan`?

---

Update:

Tried to convert `df` without naming column in the old way:

```
df.columns = ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

and

```
df= pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy(),columns=['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```

and both caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-3a27f095066b> in <module>
     12 
     13 corrMatrix = df.corr()
---> 14 sn.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True)
     15 plt.show()
     16 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in heatmap(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, linewidths, linecolor, cbar, cbar_kws, cbar_ax, square, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask, ax, **kwargs)
    545     plotter = _HeatMapper(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt,
    546                           annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels,
--> 547                           yticklabels, mask)
    548 
    549     # Add the pcolormesh kwargs here

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in __init__(self, data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask)
    164         # Determine good default values for the colormapping
    165         self._determine_cmap_params(plot_data, vmin, vmax,
--> 166                                     cmap, center, robust)
    167 
    168         # Sort out the annotations

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in _determine_cmap_params(self, plot_data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust)
    202                 vmin = np.nanpercentile(calc_data, 2)
    203             else:
--> 204                 vmin = np.nanmin(calc_data)
    205         if vmax is None:
    206             if robust:

<__array_function__ internals> in nanmin(*args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\nanfunctions.py in nanmin(a, axis, out, keepdims)
    317         # Fast, but not safe for subclasses of ndarray, or object arrays,
    318         # which do not implement isnan (gh-9009), or fmin correctly (gh-8975)
--> 319         res = np.fmin.reduce(a, axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)
    320         if np.isnan(res).any():
    321             warnings.warn("All-NaN slice encountered", RuntimeWarning,

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation fmin which has no identity
```

Comment: hmm, so error means there is `df` empty?

Comment: @jezrael It shouldn't be empty at the start, but after this plot it somehow will be.

Comment: hmmm, if use only `df = full_Data.iloc[1:,4:10]` it working?

Comment: @jezrael No, then we will have the original problem as stated in the question. It's very confusing..

Comment: OK, added 3rd solution. Should working also with empty df.

Comment: @jezrael it returned the same error`ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation fmin which has no identity` :/ Actually I don't have to rename columns as long as the heatmap works

Comment: Tested and there is 5 columns after `.iloc[1:,4:10]`, so in first and second solution removed `F`, third solution working well for me.

Comment: @jezrael I just added a sample data, please see question. Also `df.shape` showed that it's `(1150, 6)`.

Comment: Sorry `full_Data` has `(1151, 12)` in shape and so `df` is `(1150, 6)`.

Comment: It should working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is passed object `DataFrame` to `pd.DataFrame` constructor, so there are different original columns names and new columns names from list, so only `NaN`s are created.

Solution is convert it to numpy array:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy(),columns=['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```

Or set new columns names in next step without `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = full_Data.iloc[1:,4:10]
df.columns = ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Solution create `dict` by existing columns only:

```
old = df.columns
new = ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(old, new)))
print (df)
      A  B  C    D  E     F
1  2178  0  0   66  0  1207
2  1042  0  0   60  0   921
3  2096  0  0  112  0  1744
4  1832  0  0  109  0  1718
5  1341  0  0   38  0   889
6  1933  0  0  123  0  1501
```

---

```
print (df.corr())
          A   B   C         D   E         F
A  1.000000 NaN NaN  0.606808 NaN  0.727034
B       NaN NaN NaN       NaN NaN       NaN
C       NaN NaN NaN       NaN NaN       NaN
D  0.606808 NaN NaN  1.000000 NaN  0.916325
E       NaN NaN NaN       NaN NaN       NaN
F  0.727034 NaN NaN  0.916325 NaN  1.000000
```

EDIT:

Problem was columns was not numeric.

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thank you for the answer. It caught another error and I have updated the question.

Comment: `df` is actually 6 columns, `full_Data` has more columns and `df` is just a sliced piece of `full_Data`. Sorry for the confusion. But I just can't seem to think of any possible reason that caused this. I just need to get the correlation of these columns, even if it's not a plot maybe.

Comment: No, it's after `df= pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])`. It still looked normal after `df = full_Data.iloc[1:,4:10]`

Comment: @nilsinelabore - For me working well your solution, so it seems some data related issue. Are all columns numeric?

Comment: Oh I just realised they are all `object` , can we change them to numeric?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - exactly. This is problem here

Answer (score 0):

Why all the values are turned into nan?

This happened because there are 3 columns in your dataframe whose values are 0 throughout try dropping those columns and you will see nan problem to be resolved

```
  df

A   B   C   D   E   F
0   2178    1   2   6   0   1207
1   2178    3   3   66  1   1207
2   178 0   0   66  45  17
3   21  2   0   66  0   1207
4   2178    0   0   66  0   1207
5   2178    0   0   66  0   1207

df.corr()

A   B   C   D   E   F
A   1.000000    -0.023103   0.485124    -0.315890   -0.591457   0.595989
B   -0.023103   1.000000    0.713746    0.000000    -0.371648   0.387298
C   0.485124    0.713746    1.000000    -0.430007   -0.290624   0.307148
D   -0.315890   0.000000    -0.430007   1.000000    0.205308    -0.200000
E   -0.591457   -0.371648   -0.290624   0.205308    1.000000    -0.999761
F   0.595989    0.387298    0.307148    -0.200000   -0.999761   1.000000
```

where as in you case

````
df
A   B   C   D   E   F
0   2178    0   0   66  0   1207
1   2178    0   0   66  0   1207
2   2178    0   0   66  0   1207
3   2178    0   0   66  0   1207
4   2178    0   0   66  0   1207
5   2178    0   0   66  0   1207

df.corr()

A   B   C   D   E   F
A   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
B   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
C   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
D   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
E   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
F   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN```

and rest is as answered by jezrael.
````